# Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a matrix with entries in $ \mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have done quite a bit of linear algebra, but have never been confronted with a question like this and my intuition is lacking:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\ 
 4&5 
\end{bmatrix}$ where its entries are elements of $ \mathbb{Z_7}$.

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A.

So, this gives me:
\begin{bmatrix}
2 -\lambda & 3\\ 
 4&5-\lambda  
\end{bmatrix}=$(2-\lambda )(5-\lambda )-12=0$

Now comes the question: The elements of A are $\in \mathbb{Z_7}$ does this means I also need to mod out the eigenvalue equation? i.e

$(2-\lambda )(5-\lambda )-12= 10- 7 \lambda + \lambda^2 -12=$ $3+0 +\lambda^2+2 =5+ \lambda^2=0$

But this gives me imaginary eigenvalues, which leads to my second question: do the eigenvalues of A also need to be $\in \mathbb{Z_7}$?

Comment: Ah, of course - so simple. Ok, im slightly embarrassed. Thanks!

Comment: Remember $-9=5$ in this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $5+ \lambda^2=0$ does not have a real solution but it does have one in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ since $\lambda=\pm 3$ works.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, this didn't occur to me.